# Compute the norms $\|\epsilon \sin \omega t\|$ and $\|\epsilon \sin \omega t\|_{L^{\infty}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The sapce $X=C'[0,1]$ is the normed linear space  of all continuous differentiable functions on $I=[0,1]$ with norm defined by:

$$\|x\|=\max_{t \in I}|x(t)|+\max_{t \in I}|x'(t)|$$

Compute the norms $\|\epsilon \sin \omega t\|$ and $\|\epsilon \sin \omega t\|_{L^{\infty}}$ for $\epsilon >0, \omega \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$

I think for first norm $\epsilon+\epsilon \omega $ since maximum value of $\sin x$ is $1.$ but I am not sure can some help me with these norms thank you much